# cordova don'd build to android

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, compilation

I'm new at Cordova and I'm trying to solve this for two days.

When I hit the command: `Cordova run android --device` this shows up:

`C:\Users\Arthur\nameoftheapp>cordova run android --device
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Arthur\Downloads\Aprender\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-201407
02\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.`

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.354 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
  >   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0 >
  >   com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug`
  option to get more log output.
  `Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:`
  `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
  >   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0 >
  >   com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug`
  option to get more log output.

I tried to change the version in the `build.gradle` to another but when I compile, it changes back.

Comment: Your `androidSDK` is incomplete. Run `SDK Manager` and update your sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you used many cordova plugin with you'r application ?

if yes you can handle this with this plugin : https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release

Comment: what appears ??

Comment: sorry, it was not the full answer but it worked! I was doing the wrong way somehow... copied all the cordova project files without the android platform and worked! thanks!